# Google Cloud Vision not responding when using gunicorn+Flask

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, google-cloud-vision

I am new to Google Vision API but i have been working with gunicorn and flask for some time. I installed all the required libraries. i have my api key in environment via gunicorn bash file. Whenever i try to hit gcp API, it just freezes with no response.
Can anybody help?
Here's my *gunicorn_start.bash*

```
NAME="test"                                 
NUM_WORKERS=16                                     
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
FLASK_DIR=/home/user/fold/API/

echo "Starting $NAME"

cd $FLASK_DIR
conda activate tf


export development=False

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/home/user/test-6f4e7.json'
exec /home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:9349 --timeout 500 --worker-class eventlet --workers $NUM_WORKERS app:app
```

**EDIT**
It freezes during API call.
Code for API call:

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
image = vision.types.Image(content=content)


response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
```

There is no log as it just freezes,nothing else

Comment: Did it freeze before, after o during the API call? Also, it would be really helpful if you could provide the code that is making the request, and any log message that might help determine what is the issue.

Comment: @TIaquetzal Please go through the EDIT. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine and it doesn't seem to be a permission error. Since there are no logs, the issue is hard to troubleshoot; however, I have two theories of what could be happening. I'll leave them below, with some information on how to troubleshoot them.

**The API call is not reaching Google's servers**

This could be happening due to a networking error. To discard this, try to make a request from the development environment (or where the application is running) using `curl`.

You can follow the [CLI quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-cli#top_of_page) for Vision API to prepare the environment, and make the request. If it works, then you can discard the network as a possible cause. If the request fails or freezes, then you might need to check the network configuration of your environment.

In addition, you can go to the [API Dashboard in the Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/monitoring#top_of_page) and look at the metrics of the Vision API. In these graphs, you can see if your requests are reaching the server, as well as some useful information like: errors by API method, errors by credential, latency of requests, etc.

**There's an issue with the image/document you're sending**

> Note: Change the logging level of the application to DEBUG (if it's not already at this level).

If you're certain that the requests are reaching the server, the possible issue could be with the file that you're trying to send. If the file is too big, the connection might look as if it was frozen while it is being uploaded, and also it might take some time to be processed. Try with smaller files to see the results.

Also, I noticed that you're currently using a synchronous method to perform the recognition. If the file is too big, you could try the asynchronous annotation approach. Basically, you upload your file(s) to Cloud Storage first and then create a request indicating: the storage URI where your file is located and the destination storage URI where you want the results to be written to.

What you'll receive from the service is an operation Id. With this Id, you can check the status of the recognition request and make your code wait until the process has finished. You can use [this example](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#document_text_detection_requests) as a reference to implement it.

Hopefully with this information you can determine what is the issue you're facing and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and it turned out to be gunicorn's fault. When I switched to the Django dev server, the problem went away. I tried with older gunicorn versions (back to 2018), and the problem persisted. I should probably report this to gunicorn. :D

Going to switch to uwsgi in the meantime.